# Issue accessing DataContext from user control on page in frame

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, uwp

Struggling to find a solution to this issue that I am having, I have a UWP App that I have been toying around with and for the most part have been able to work things out.

The issue I am facing is with a Hambuger Menu, I have a frame that I load a page up, which displays a gridview of items. When clicked it then displays another page in that frame.

The new page has this which I am able to display data in the page no issue at all.

```
public sealed partial class CreatureDossier : Page
{
    private Species Cat;

    public CreatureDossier()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Cat = (Species)e.Parameter;
    }
}
```

In the XAML of this page I am putting a UserControl that I would like to use the data that is present and is where I a struggling. Every time I break on the User Control it shows the DataContext as empty (null).

I have tried

```
<UIControls:DossierPanel />
```

Really not understanding what I am needing to do to make this User Control use the DataContext, I should point out that I have this in the UserControl but as stated the DataContext is null.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CatName" Text="{Binding Cat.name}" />
```

Now the interesting thing is that if I use a property called Cat on the Usercontrol with a normal text string and a DependencyProperty in the UserControl code behind, I can display that with this.DataContext = this in the constructor.

User Control code behind

```
public sealed partial class DossierPanel : UserControl
{
    public Models.Species Cat { get { return this.DataContext as Models.Species; } }

    public DossierPanel()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

CreatureDossier.xaml

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="CreatureName" Text="{x:Bind Cat.name}" />
    <UIControls:DossierPanel  />
```

Any help in understanding what I need to do would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataContext` of the `Page`:

```
public sealed partial class CreatureDossier : Page
{
    private Species Cat;

    public CreatureDossier()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Cat = (Species)e.Parameter;
        DataContext = Cat;
    }
}
```

The `UserControl` will then inherit the `DataContext` from the `Page` (assuming that you don't explicitly set the DataContext property somewhere else) and you should be able to bind to any public property of the `Species` class like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CatName" Text="{Binding name}" />
```

**Edit:**
`{x:Bind}` doesn't use the `DataContext` as a default source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

But if you give the `UserControl` an `x:Name`:

```
<UIControls:DossierPanel x:Name="uc"  />
```

...and add a setter to the `Cat` property:

```
public sealed partial class DossierPanel : UserControl
{
    public Models.Species Cat { get; set; }

    public DossierPanel()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And set this one:

```
public sealed partial class CreatureDossier : Page
{
    public CreatureDossier()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        uc.Cat = (Species)e.Parameter;
    }
}
```

---

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CatName" Text="{Binding Cat.name, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, while it sets the DataContext to Cat this page already has the data to display the information prior to this. The User Control on the other hand is still showing the DataContext as null. Should I be using the initial way of a DP to pass the Cat Object over to the UserControl?

Originally I had this

    public sealed partial class DossierPanel : UserControl
    {
        public Models.Species Cat { get { return this.DataContext as Models.Species; } }

        public DossierPanel()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

Comment: You should not set the DataContext of the DossierPanel. Are you doing this? Please read this and modify your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No I am not setting the DataContext in the DossierPanel, there is a read only property to return the data and that is it.

Comment: Once again, you need to provide *all* relevant code snippets for anyone to be able to help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the code posted in previous comment.

Comment: What does the TextBlock display if you bind to the DataContext itself like this: Text="{Binding Path=.}" ?

Comment: Displays nothing

Comment: If you handle the Loaded event for the TextBlock and check the value of its DataContext property in a debug session, what it is set to?

Comment: Do you mean as in the xaml part for the User Control? Not familiar with how to do it for the actual TextBlock

Comment: {x:Bind} doesn't use the DataContext...see my edited answer and read the link once more.

Comment: Well the interesting thing is that the loaded event I put on the User Control, shows that it has the data that should be there. Let me have a look at what you have done and get back to you.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it is still displaying nothing. Oh wait I missed the binding, once sec

Comment: Yep still nothing

Comment: I know have this working.

By going back to where I was headed I changed the UserControl TextBlock

<TextBlock x:Name="CatName" Text="{X:Bind Cat.name}" />

It now works.